# Showing all x axis label for discrete variable in ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels, zoo

I have a set of data and I want to plot a bar plot for the data. The example of data is shown below:

```
   yq        flag      n ratio
   <yearqtr> <fct> <int> <dbl>
 1 2011 Q1   0       269 0.610
 2 2011 Q1   1       172 0.390
 3 2011 Q2   0       266 0.687
 4 2011 Q2   1       121 0.313
 5 2011 Q3   0       239 0.646
 6 2011 Q3   1       131 0.354
 7 2011 Q4   0       153 0.668
 8 2011 Q4   1        76 0.332
 9 2012 Q1   0       260 0.665
10 2012 Q1   1       131 0.335
11 2012 Q2   0       284 0.676
12 2012 Q2   1       136 0.324
13 2012 Q3   0       197 0.699
14 2012 Q3   1        85 0.301
15 2012 Q4   0       130 0.688
16 2012 Q4   1        59 0.312
17 2013 Q1   0       273 0.705
18 2013 Q1   1       114 0.295
19 2013 Q2   0       333 0.729
20 2013 Q2   1       124 0.271
```

What I want to do is basically plotting the ratio for each flag in each quarter. I wrote the code below:

```
data$flag <- as.factor(data$flag)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=yq, y=ratio, fill=flag)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))
```

The result is shown below:

[image: result of code]

But what I actually want is to show all quarters on the x-axis and maybe in vertical form for better visualization. I tried using `scale_x_discrete(limits=yq)` however, this is not the correct answer and return an error. How can I do this?

Comment: Next time, please provide your data as `dput(data)`, would save us some time trying to re-create your data.

Comment: @zx8754 You are right. I should have done it. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using *zoo* package, then set the *scale_x_yearqtr* with custom breaks:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = yq, y = ratio, fill = flag)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge())+
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = unique(data$yq)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#999999', '#E69F00'))
```

[image]

Then if needed just flip:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = yq, y = ratio, fill = flag)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge())+
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = unique(data$yq)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#999999', '#E69F00')) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

#### Data

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(yq = structure(c(2011, 2011, 2011.25, 2011.25, 
2011.5, 2011.5, 2011.75, 2011.75, 2012, 2012, 2012.25, 2012.25, 
2012.5, 2012.5, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2013, 2013, 2013.25, 2013.25
), class = "yearqtr"), flag = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), n = c(269L, 172L, 266L, 121L, 239L, 
131L, 153L, 76L, 260L, 131L, 284L, 136L, 197L, 85L, 130L, 59L, 
273L, 114L, 333L, 124L), ratio = c(0.61, 0.39, 0.687, 0.313, 
0.646, 0.354, 0.668, 0.332, 0.665, 0.335, 0.676, 0.324, 0.699, 
0.301, 0.688, 0.312, 0.705, 0.295, 0.729, 0.271)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Exactly! I used the `zoo` package to generate `year/quarter`. Thanks, this resolved the issue. can you please explain what exactly `scale_x_yearqtr` doing? I used to see `scale_x_discrete` or `scale_x_continous` and this function is totally new for me

Comment: @Roozbeh_you , manual for `scale_x_yearqtr` is pretty clear, it helps with plotting zoo objects: "Convenience Functions for Plotting zoo Objects with ggplot2". I am just setting custom breaks, based on data unique quarter values.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `yq` column is in year-quarter format (as defined in the `zoo` package). For ggplot, it might be best to convert this to date format and specify the breaks like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

data$flag <- as.factor(data$flag)

ggplot(data=data, aes(as.Date(yq), ratio, fill = flag)) +
  geom_col(color="black", position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  labs(x = "Year / Quarter") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00')) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Or you could stack the columns:

```r
ggplot(data=data, aes(as.Date(yq), ratio, fill = flag)) +
  geom_col(color="black", position = position_stack()) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  labs(x = "Year / Quarter") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00')) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
data <- structure(list(yq = structure(c(2011, 2011, 2011.25, 2011.25, 
2011.5, 2011.5, 2011.75, 2011.75, 2012, 2012, 2012.25, 2012.25, 
2012.5, 2012.5, 2012.75, 2012.75, 2013, 2013, 2013.25, 2013.25
), class = "yearqtr"), flag = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), n = c(269L, 
172L, 266L, 121L, 239L, 131L, 153L, 76L, 260L, 131L, 284L, 136L, 
197L, 85L, 130L, 59L, 273L, 114L, 333L, 124L), ratio = c(0.61, 
0.39, 0.687, 0.313, 0.646, 0.354, 0.668, 0.332, 0.665, 0.335, 
0.676, 0.324, 0.699, 0.301, 0.688, 0.312, 0.705, 0.295, 0.729, 
0.271)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% 
  mutate(yq=factor(yq,levels = rev(unique(yq)),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=yq, y=ratio, fill=factor(flag))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(df$yq))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))+
  coord_flip()+labs(fill='flag')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=yq, y=ratio, fill=factor(flag))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(df$yq))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#999999','#E69F00'))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))+labs(fill='flag')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(yq = c("2011 Q1", "2011 Q1", "2011 Q2", "2011 Q2", 
"2011 Q3", "2011 Q3", "2011 Q4", "2011 Q4", "2012 Q1", "2012 Q1", 
"2012 Q2", "2012 Q2", "2012 Q3", "2012 Q3", "2012 Q4", "2012 Q4", 
"2013 Q1", "2013 Q1", "2013 Q2", "2013 Q2"), flag = c(0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), n = c(269, 
172, 266, 121, 239, 131, 153, 76, 260, 131, 284, 136, 197, 85, 
130, 59, 273, 114, 333, 124), ratio = c(0.61, 0.39, 0.687, 0.313, 
0.646, 0.354, 0.668, 0.332, 0.665, 0.335, 0.676, 0.324, 0.699, 
0.301, 0.688, 0.312, 0.705, 0.295, 0.729, 0.271)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess the second graph is what I am looking for; however, when I tried to follow your code, I got an error message in `scale_x_discrete` like before. the error is : `Error: "mapped_discrete" objects can only be created from numeric vectors`. So should I create a seprate vecore from `yq` and pass it to the function to resolve it?

Comment: Thanks, Duck, I guess @zx8754 answered my question. It seems that the error message is because of the type of data which is the result of `zoo` package. I should have provided, so you knew what type of data you are dealing with. Lesson learned!